# Wordpress - Targeting Individual POST, rather than POST Type. AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load the individual post information on click into the page when clicking the post title. I have managed to get my script to loop through the titles in the post array and on click load the post titles once more into a div. I want this to load the individual post information instead on click.

PHP Post Array Functions -

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_success_stories", "sa_get_paginated_posts" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_success_stories", "sa_get_paginated_posts" );

function sa_get_paginated_posts(){

      $args = array(
          'posts_per_page'  => -1,
          'post_type'       => 'success-stories',
          'orderby'         => 'post_date',
          'order'           => 'DESC' 
      );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      $queryitems = $the_query->get_posts();
      $alldata = array();

      if ($queryitems){

        foreach ($queryitems as $query_item){

          $success_story = array();

          $success_story["ID"] = $query_item->ID;
          $success_story["title"] = $query_item->post_title;

          $alldata[] = $success_story;

        }

      }

      $encoded_data = json_encode($alldata);

      echo $encoded_data;

      die();

  }



function sa_get_posts($post_amount, $post_type){

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => $post_amount,
        'post_type'       => $post_type,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'ASC'

    );
```

Using this function to loop through -

```
      <? if ($success_stories): //success story posts ?>
            <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
                <? foreach ($success_stories as $success_story): 
                    $title = $success_story->post_title; ?>

                    <li><a data-id="<? echo $success_story->ID; ?>" class="success-extra" href="#" title=""><? echo $title; ?></a></li>

                <? endforeach; ?>
            </ul>

          <div id="success-list"></div>
          <a class="success-close" href="#" title="">CLOSE</a>

    <? endif; ?>
```

Javascript/ AJAX Call

```
  var $json_response_box = $("#success-list");

  function get_ajax_success_posts() {

    //this line gets the id attribute from the link
    var current_story = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(current_story);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "WORDPRESSDIRECTORY/admin-ajax.php",
        cache: true,
        data: {
            action: "success_stories"
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

            var arrayLength = data.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {


                var success_id = data[i].ID;
                var success_title = data[i].title;

                console.log(success_id);

                story = '<ul>';
                  story += '<li>';
                    story += success_title;
                  story += '</li>';
                story += '</ul>'; 

                $json_response_box.append(story).fadeIn(1000);

            }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            console.log("fail-posts");
        }
    });
  }
```

Appreciate your suggestions,

D

Comment: Hmmm, I don't fully understand. What is your PHP code? You can easily add data-id to the title, on click submit it via AJAX to your plugin, use  get_post($id) to get post details  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post and return it to your Ajax success function...

Comment: Hi, I have just updated the post with the PHP functions that are used. Just wondering how i would edit the AJAX function to target the specific post. Im struggling with the syntax

Comment: Yes, there's more code than explanation about the issue. I don't understand this: *"I want this to load the individual post information instead on click"*. Reading the code doesn't tell me anything about any issue. . . . Observations: **1)** What `function sa_get_posts()` has to do with the problem?   **2)** I'd do simply `$queryitems = get_posts( $args );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just add another php function and AJAX call, to get the post on click, something like this (I also added nonce to add some secutiry, it's always a good idea to add that to your ajax calls)

HTML:

```
<li><a data-id="<? echo $success_story->ID; ?>" data-nonce="<?php wp_create_nonce('get_post'.$success_story->ID); ?>" class="success-extra" href="#" title=""><? echo $title; ?></a></li>
```

PHP:

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_sa_get_post", "sa_get_post" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_sa_get_post", "sa_get_post" );

function sa_get_post(){
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'get_post_'.$POST['id'] ) ) {
    // This nonce is not valid.
    $response['status'] = 'fail'; 
    } else {
    // The nonce was valid.
    $post = get_post($POST['id']);
    $response['status'] = 'success'; 
    $response['post'] = $post;        
    } 
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit(); // this is needed, as otherwise the AJAX returns an extra 0       
}
```

JS:

```
 $('.success-extra').on('click', function () {
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WORDPRESSDIRECTORY/admin-ajax.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: "sa_get_post",
            id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
            nonce: $(this).attr('data-nonce')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (result.status != 'success') {
               // display error messago or something
            } else {

              // do whatever you want with your result.post
            }
        }

 })
```

Hope this helps.